# Finding the Remainder after Division in C

Tags: c

You need to use division and remainder by 10,

Consider this example,

```
163 divided by 10 is 16 and remainder is 3
16 divided by 10 is 1 and remainder is 6
1 divided by 10 is 0 and remainder is 1
```

Notice that the remainder is always the last digit of the number that's being divided.

How can I do this in `C`?

Comment: If your question is about C, why the C# tag? And this looks like homework, you should tag it appropriately.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like homework so I won't give you code, but I suggest you research the [modulo operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) and how this could be used to solve your assignment.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Modulus operator:

```
 remainder = 163 % 10; // remainder is 3
```

It works for any number too:

```
  remainder = 17 % 8;  // remainder is 1, since 8*2=16
```

(This works for both C and C#)

Answer (score 1):

With the [modulus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) operator (`%`):

```
15 % 12 == 3
17 % 8 == 1
```

Comment: ok how would i then make the results an individual variable for futher calculations?

Comment: Simply assign the result of the modulus operation to another int variable, the same as you would with `+` or `*`.