# Values of integers and calculations

Tags: c

Say you have a variable `n1` which will be the value of three digits entered.
How can I then split `n1` into 3 seperate integers, without knowing what exactly will be input?

Comment: Is n1 just three digits as a string? So for example "402"? And you want to return three integers 4, 0 and 2.

Comment: @inferno2991: are you starting with a string as input? Or would you like us to split an integer into digits? It is not clear, judging from the answers... :P

Comment: well the purpose is to not use strings

Comment: @inferno2991: We're just wondering what the type is of the input variable, so we can answer your question.

Comment: well the program would ask insert a number
so for example they insert 692 
whish is then n1 i want to split n1 into three seperate variables so i can perform calculations with each indivdual number

Comment: @inferno2991: What type is n1? A `string`, an `int`, or something else?

Comment: What i am trying to achieve is to hyphinate a 13 digit number as so 1234567891234

123-456789-123-4
where i have n1 n2 n3 n4 to differntiate the sections with hyphens i then want to go onto use each of the individual 13 digits for calculations i use n1-n4 cause i didnt noe how to assign 13 digits to individual variables and then make the hyphenated output.

Comment: @inferno2991: Why not use strings? It is much simpler and the user is probably entering the input as a string anyway so it might also be faster instead of first converting to an int and then using modular arithmetic to get the individual digits back.

Comment: n1 is an int and this is a task that isnt supposed to use strings

Comment: @inferno2991: But why exactly isn't it supposed to use strings? Is it a homework question? If so, it would be easier if you just posted your homework assignment verbatim instead of rephrasing it in a very vague way.

Comment: @inferno2991: Ah yes now I remember. You posted another homework question but didn't tag it as such. You should remember the homework tag. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531295/help-in-c-with-integers

Comment: https://wiki.cse.unsw.edu.au/cs1917cgi/10s1/Task1

theres what im meant to do sorry for vague explanations

Comment: @inferno2991:  That looks like it is in C, not C#.

Comment: i thought they were the same thing :S

Comment: @inferno2991: The link says: `ALL work submitted for this assignment MUST BE YOUR OWN WORK and it MUST BE COMPLETED INDIVIDUALLY. DO NOT COPY FROM OTHERS; DO NOT ALLOW ANYONE TO SEE YOUR CODE.`  I'll delete my answer.

Comment: inferno2991: C and C# are not even close to being the same. I'm going to fix the tag.

Comment: @inferno2991: As I have read, your code should be in C. Also, your code must be original - don't forget that anyone can search the internet. That is I guess one of the reasons why on SO no one seems to provide code for homework - only suggestions. It is a good idea and might be in your best interest to indicate that a question is homework.

Comment: ah thanks anyways im just not too good with c and this has all got me stumped

Comment: @Zach: you could have just left it there. I'm sure `gcc` would have happily cut through the code resolving e.g. ToString(). :P

Comment: @inferno2991: If you could rephrase your question and tell us what you have tried, the StackOverflow community will be happy to help you solve the particular difficulty.  What is discouraged (for your own sake), though, is trying to get other people to do your homework for you.

Comment: @Zach i can do stage 1 

 printf("Enter Barcode:");

        scanf("%3lld %6lld %3lld %lld \n",&n1, &n2, &n3,&n4 );

        printf("Barcode Is: %3lld-%06lld-%03lld-%0lld\n",n1,n2,n3,n4);

but when i get to the checksum stage i dont noe how to the checksum without having individual variables for each interger rather than the grouped variables i use now

Comment: @inferno2991: I think andras's answer may be what you are looking for.  BTW, it would be a good idea to edit your question with that information, so it will be more visible.

Answer (score 5):

divide by 10 in a loop and take the modulo?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that you do actually want to use a string. What you want to do is read a string as input and then break it down into the various segments. You would find the first 3 digits and turn it into an integer in n1, then read the next 2 digits and turn them into n2, etc.